# Variable of reference type..terminology problem

Tags: c#, terminology

Having following code:

```
 class X
    {
      public void Y(){}
    }


    X _x=new X();
    _x.Y();  //should I say Y is method of _x variable? It is easy but actually the variable contains just reference to object that has this method

   X newX=x;   //here I assign the value of variable x to variable newX. The value is reference
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my most pedantic mood, I would write:

> `Y` is a parameterless instance method declared in type `X`. It is invoked on the object referred to by the value of `_x`.

(`_x` itself is neither the object nor the reference - it's the variable.)

Comment: I am asking as in the book I currently read they often say: Use method XY of variable A.

Comment: In a mood even more pedantic than your most pedantic mood you would drop the `()` in `Y()`. :-)

Comment: @Lojol: It's not entirely unreasonable, so long as you know what they mean. I tend to be pedantic when I'm discussing the topic of exactly what happens as part of method invocation - but if I'm *really* only interested in (say) string manipulation, I won't be quite as precise with the terminology, as it ends up being more longwinded than it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

`Y` is a pubilc instance method on the class `X` being invoked on the instance of the class `X` referred to by `_x`.

As an aside, an invocation like this is actually compiled as something like

```
call X::Y(_x)
```

This is because every instance-level method has an implicit first parameter that is a reference to the object that the method is being invoked on (this is how `this` refers to the right object).

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's not much of a problem because classes and variables have descriptive names, so it's pretty clear what's what.

An example using an actual class:

`builder` is a variable containing a reference to an instance of the `StringBuilder` class:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
```

The `Append` method is a method in the `StringBuilder` class, not a method in the `builder` variable. You are calling the method on the instance that `builder` is referring to:

```
builder.Append("asdf");
```